# How to number theorems starting with a prefix `n`: theorem n.1

Tags: numbering, theorems

I am writing lecture notes in different files. So I want the theorems in the `Lecture 1` file like

Theorem 1.1

Theorem 1.2

...

And, theorems in `Lecture 2` file like

Theorem 2.1

Theorem 2.2

...

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will assume that you're using a package such as `amsthm` or `ntheorem` and use commands such as `\newtheorem` to create theorem-like environments. If this is the case, I suggest you create a LaTeX counter called, say, `lecturenum`, set this counter to the appropriate number (e.g., 3), and then use `\newtheorem` directives to create theorem-like environments that use the value of  `lecturenum` as a prefix to the theorem numbers.

That way, the only setup instruction that has to be adjusted across the preambles of the `lecture_n.tex` files is the instruction

```
\setcounter{lecturenum}{n} % this is lecture "n" (e.g, 3)
```

---

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class

\newcounter{lecturenum}
\setcounter{lecturenum}{5} % this is lecture 5

\usepackage{amsthm} % or 'ntheorem'
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[lecturenum]

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem} bla bla bla \end{theorem}
\begin{theorem} ble ble ble \end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I need.